# Same constraints different results

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I gave a value of -8 to the "bottom to Safe Area bottom" constraints of 2 views, but they are not showing at the same distance from the Safe Area (seems like one needs -16 to equalize them).

#### What could be the issue?

Here's some code:

```swift
    func addPlayerViews() { // called in viewDidLoad
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.smallView.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.backgroundColor = .white
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.shadowColor = myShadowColor
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            self.smallView.myLittleSubview.layer.shadowRadius = 4
           

            self.bigView.backgroundColor = .white
            self.bigView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            self.bigView.layer.shadowColor = myShadowColor
            self.bigView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -3.0)
            self.bigView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.bigView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            self.bigView.layer.shadowRadius = 4

            self.view.addSubview(self.smallView)
            self.view.addSubview(self.bigView)

            self.smallView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.bigView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let safeArea = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                self.smallView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
                self.smallView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                self.smallView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
                self.smallView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48),
                self.bigView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                    equalTo: self.smallView.myLittleSubview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                self.bigView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                self.bigView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
                // ☝️ not working as expected. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62602071/5306470
                self.bigView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 270)
            ])


            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // must be at end of animation block, it seems

        }

    }
```

## Screenshot

- Big view is blue and semi-transparent, myLittleSubview is orange, and smallView is `.clear`
- iPhone 11 Pro Max (13.5)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In general, it is not enough to add just the bottom constraints. From the docs: 
"In general, the constraints must define both the size and the position of each view. [...] a nonambiguous, satisfiable layout requires two constraints per view per dimension" (see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1)
Have you added sufficient vertical constraints? You must also set horizontal constraints for auto layout to work properly.

Comment: @Jordan I think I did. I was not sure how much code to include. I will add more constraints from my code.

Comment: @Jordan added some. I notice that it might be hard to tell what's going on since "mySubview" is not declared in code, but the issue here is with bottom spacing, not leading, so I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: @Jordan if you found this post well asked, an upvote would be great.

Comment: You add this constraint twice: viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
And you must set either a height constraint or a top constraint for both views A and B.

Comment: @Jordan that was a pasting mistake, and I already have height constraints as well. Edited.

Comment: Alright, the constraints now look good to me, thanks for the update. Have you tried setting the constant value for the bottom constraint on both views to 0? Are they aligned then? Sometime it does not act as expected when using negative values. Sometimes you have to make one constant negative and the constant on another view positive to achieve the same distance.

Comment: With both set to 0, bigView is lower down than myLittleSubview

Comment: Ok, now I see you are using 3 different views: smallView, bigView and myLittleSubview. All of them need 2 constraints vertical and 2 horizontal.

Comment: @Jordan I shall G-d willing be back Monday, thank you!